# How to get and params value in bracket?

Tags: grails

I received params like,

```
value[city] : foo
value[country] : bar
value[zipcode] : 1234
```

How can I get params value.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please annotate more clear, what the param actually is (key/value pairs from a map where one is `'value[city]': 'foo'` ?) are you generating those values on your own?  do you use databinding?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting value in form of .

```
value[city : foo,country : bar, zipcode:1234]
```

you can get value using .

```
params['value.city']
params['value.country']
params['value.zipcode']
```